# Why I can print a String, but throws error when I try to store it in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, string, swift5

I have a pretty basic code, that makes 2 String.Index ranges from an existing `websiteContent` String like so:

```
let test1 = websiteContent.range(of: startString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: websiteContent.startIndex..<websiteContent.endIndex)

let test2 = websiteContent.range(of: endString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: websiteContent.startIndex..<websiteContent.endIndex)
```

Then it prints the text between the 2 ranges:

```
if let beginning = test1, let end = test2 {
    print(websiteContent[beginning.lowerBound..<end.upperBound])
}
```

This works just fine, my problem is that when I try to store this String value I just printed it throws an error message. The way I tried to store it is this:

```
if let beginning = test1, let end = test2 {
    let why : String = websiteContent[beginning.lowerBound..<end.upperBound]
}
```

And the error message says: *Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires the types 'String.Index' and 'Int' be equivalent*

Could you please help me understand what do I do wrong?

Comment: String(websiteContent[beginning.lowerBound..<end.upperBound]) should fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug, the error is misleading.

You have to create a `String` from the `Substring`, annotating the type is not sufficient.

```
if let beginning = test1, let end = test2 {
    let why = String(websiteContent[beginning.lowerBound..<end.upperBound])
}
```

Side note:

You can omit `, range: websiteContent.startIndex..<websiteContent.endIndex`, the range of the whole string is the default.

Comment: I think you answered an identical question before ...

Comment: @MartinR I admire you for remembering all those things.

Comment: WOW thank you for your help! And to think just how much time I could have save just by not defining variable type... ohh man